# Javascript return issue

Tags: javascript

This problem has just become apparent in some historical code and seems to be an issue relating to IE8 + and FF4 +

I have a js file that validates a contact form, one particular section calls a function to open a new window with some info for the user.  At this point the script seems to ignore my `valid = false` variable (which is flagged to stop form submission)

```
function showFormat() {
    var myWindow;
    myWindow = window.open("http://url/page.html","Postcode_Information","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=640,height=400");
    myWindow.moveTo(50,50);
}
```

Above code is causing the issue.  i've tried adding `valid=false; return valid;` to the end of the function but it is apparently being ignored.  Adding this to the begining of the function means that the validity is correct and the form doesnt submit but obviously my new window doesnt open.

**EDIT TO EXPLAIN IN MORE DETAIL**

My js file has a series of validation functions (checking username, address, email address validity etc).  A variable is initialised called `valid` which will always be true unless any user input does not validate, in which case `valid = false`.

If `valid = false` then an if statement is run which checks against a number of variables in order to determine which area of the validation has caused the problem and will flag up an appropriate prompt.  Most of these are done via a message box (I inherited this code and am merely trying to get it working) but one prompt opens up a new window.  If any of these prompts are called at all then the form should not be submitted.

The problem I am having is that when this new window opens (and this is the only prompt causing this issue) the form will still submit.

See code below for an example of when these prompts are called:

```
if (!valid) {
       if (emailNoAddress == true) {
           alert('You have requested to receive more information by email from other company(ies) but have not provided email address details – Please correct this below');
           highlightEmail();
       }
       else {
           if (contactDetails == false) {
               alert('Please provide your email address details. We will not send you future correspondence and offers by email if you prefer us not to.');
               highlightAddress();
               highlightEmail();
           }
               else {
               if (postcodeGiven == false) {
                            if (dataform.pcode.value == "") {
                                alert('Please enter a valid postcode');
                                }
                            else {
                                showFormat();
                                }           
               }

               else {
                   if (questionsAnswered == false || countryGiven == false) {
                       alert('Please choose an answer from the options provided');
                   }
                   else {
                        //alert(checkstr);
                       alert('Could you please complete the questions missing details');
                   }
               }
           }                            
       }
   }
```

So you see, my function can only be called when `!valid` in which case the form should not submit but as soon as I execute the new window function `showformat()` it allows the form to be submitted.

**EDIT - UPDATE**

I've managed to narrow the problem down slightly in  that after the new window opens, no more script is executed (i've tried adding a few alert messages to check the value of `valid` but they are not shown - I've also tried adding a breakpoint while debugging with Firebug but this is not hit) and the form submits regardless...

**EDIT - UPDATE**

Beacuse this was a time-critical issue, for the moment I have just put all the text from the pop-up window into an alert and call that instead of the function.  When I have any more time to spend investigatin I will update.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Not sure what the valid variable does in this context. Maybe you can explain your question a bit more with some more example code maybe?

Comment: can you put you `valid` bool in the context of the code you provided? What you put so far is not enough.

Comment: The code you posted is totally not relevant. It does not even contain the word "valid". Please post **relevant** code and we might be able to help.

Comment: Basically, if the above function is called, my javascript should not allow a form submission but currently it is.  This function is only called when a variable (`valid`) is already set to `false` so I am assuming that it is somehow being reset or ignored completely after this function is called?

Comment: Question has now been updated

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the onsubmit event defined on the form tag? If so then add the keyword **return** in the onsubmit event like shown below
onsubmit = "return some_function" and in the function called u have to specify **return false**. Then u will be getting wat u want.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have this 
`if (valid) {return true;} else {return false;}` at the end of my function to return a value already, so I think `valid` must be being reset somewhere?

Comment: first put a alert within the if and else condition to check whether the value of the valid is true or false

Comment: I've added the alert to check - `valid` is defiantely false when it hits my `showformat()` function.  As soon as that executes and the new window opens though, I can't get any further output or alerts to display and my js must be returning true to my html submit form as it then submits the form

Comment: Where are you calling the function showFormat ? Is it called in the form tag or called within someother function?

Comment: If you see my edit to the original question, it is called from inside the function that is called from the form tag (my code above is not the entire function, only the relevant section)

Comment: then simple just add a **return** keyword infront of the function call showFormat and then u return a value from the function showFormat by checking the value of the variable valid. U will get it done

Comment: Thanks for your help up to now, but this is where I am experiencing problems.  I've tried just retruning false at the end of my `showformat()` functino but the form is still submitting so I think this return has been ignored - are there any known compatibility issues with `window.open` and any of the newer browsers that you are aware of?

Comment: @allanmayberry88 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2803/discussion-between-amgates-and-allanmayberry88)

Comment: sorry for not continuing in chat, I had left my desk when you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SImple example which works as u need. Try this and correct ur code accordingly

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            if(document.forms[0].stext.value!="")
            {
                return showformat();
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        function showformat()
        {
            window.open("new.html","");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <form name="sample" action="onsel.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" name="stext" id="stext" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Have u tried executing this example. If so it would have answered ur question. Try executing it.. This example gives me the output as you expect so it will be helpful for you

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help up to now but as I have explained, your example looks like what I have already got in place - the problem is that once the new window opens in my example - no values seem to be returned from that function and the rest of the script on my page that should run seems to be ignored

Comment: Did u notice how am i calling the showformat function? ok if possible can u send me ur code to my mail id and I will get it done for you.

Comment: Have u tried running my example locally on your machine? If not do it and see u can see the line "return false" after window.open will be executed.

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried your example and it does work - and as I say it is a problem with the code not returning a false value (I have tried calling the function with a return as you have in your example).  Unfortunately I am not able to send you all my code, and at the moment I don't have any more time to spend on this as there are other projects needing work - the client is happy enough with the message box just now, not pretty but it does the job.  I will be coming back to this in the next week or so and will update with progress.  Thank you for all your help so far.